# how to connect android application with magento

Tags: magento-1.9, android

I am developing an android application with backend magento, I already created User and Role in System-web services-SOAP but when I run this url on browser
http://www.my_website_name.com/index.php/api/v2_soap.

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<SOAP-ENV:Fault>
<faultcode>WSDL</faultcode>
<faultstring>
SOAP-ERROR: Parsing Schema: can't import schema from 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/'
</faultstring>
</SOAP-ENV:Fault>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I have one more URL which is also connected to magento with same SOAP api and all as above and i can easily able to fetch data from the magento.

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<SOAP-ENV:Fault>
<faultcode>Sender</faultcode>
<faultstring>Invalid XML</faultstring>
</SOAP-ENV:Fault>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 4):

The correct URL to use is:

`http://www.my_website_name.com/index.php/api/v2_soap?wsdl=1`

Note the additional `?wsdl=1` parameter in the URL.